# PhotoEditor SDK crash on Android 6.0 when adding text

Tags: android, react-native, photoeditorsdk

We have a React Native app that uses the PhotoEditor SDK and it crashes when adding text. It only happens on Android 6.0 though, but not on 4.4, 5.0, 7.0, 8.0, and 8.1. I'm testing in the emulator.

When confirming the addition of some text by tapping the checkmark. I see for a moment the rectangle, with a black background, that the text should occupy and then the alert "Unfortunately, [my app] has stopped." and the app is restarted.

The Logcat shows...

```
06-28 16:55:49.206 5012-5012/com.myapp D/PESDK_EVENTS: current tool changed to: Text Options
06-28 16:55:49.248 5012-5012/com.myapp D/PESDK_EVENTS: add text
06-28 16:55:49.344 5012-5012/com.myapp D/PESDK_EVENTS: current tool changed to: Text Options
06-28 16:55:49.526 1222-1275/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 151552
06-28 16:55:49.586 5012-5191/com.myapp D/FA: Connected to remote service


    --------- beginning of crash
06-28 16:55:49.624 5012-5264/com.myapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xe0ba8000 in tid 5264 (pool-14-thread-)
06-28 16:55:49.734 1314-1314/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:6.0/MASTER/4729342:userdebug/test-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    ABI: 'x86'
    pid: 5012, tid: 5264, name: pool-14-thread-  >>> com.myapp <<<
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xe0ba8000
06-28 16:55:49.753 1314-1314/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00024ea0  ebx ea3edeb4  ecx 00006ba8  edx eab8cb1c
        esi d8d8b000  edi e0ba8000
06-28 16:55:49.754 1314-1314/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 0000019f  xss 0000002b
        eip ea3e7a38  ebp 003fffc4  esp d8d3e644  flags 00210202
06-28 16:55:49.759 1314-1314/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 00002a38  /system/lib/libOpenglSystemCommon.so (goldfish_dma_write(goldfish_dma_context*, void*, unsigned int)+56)
        #01 pc 00003853  /system/lib/libOpenglSystemCommon.so (ExtendedRCEncoderContext::lockAndWriteDma(void*, unsigned int)+67)
        #02 pc 00003062  /system/lib/lib_renderControl_enc.so
        #03 pc 0000314e  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.ranchu.so
        #04 pc 0000a351  /system/lib/libui.so (android::GraphicBufferMapper::unlockAsync(native_handle const*, int*)+113)
        #05 pc 000086f1  /system/lib/libui.so (android::GraphicBuffer::unlockAsync(int*)+49)
        #06 pc 0006bae6  /system/lib/libgui.so (android::Surface::unlockAndPost()+70)
        #07 pc 000b6b00  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
06-28 16:55:49.760 1314-1314/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 72fd7746  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1eb2000)
06-28 16:55:50.013 1314-1314/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_04
06-28 16:55:50.013 1314-1314/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe

    --------- beginning of system
06-28 16:55:50.014 1633-1658/system_process I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
06-28 16:55:50.067 1633-5279/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.myapp/ly.img.android.ui.activities.PhotoEditorActivity
06-28 16:55:50.168 1633-1643/system_process I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 22042(1614KB) AllocSpace objects, 11(1272KB) LOS objects, 20% free, 10MB/12MB, paused 1.532ms total 134.410ms
06-28 16:55:50.204 1764-2252/com.android.systemui D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f278d83dba0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7f2784e0c7e0)
06-28 16:55:50.221 1633-3597/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-28 16:55:50.227 1633-3597/system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7f277f848fe0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
06-28 16:55:50.230 1633-3597/system_process D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f277f848fe0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7f278056cbe0)
06-28 16:55:50.231 1633-3597/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
...
```

Sometimes, not sure how, I see these other logs for the same crash...

```
06-27 14:29:29.440 5014-5159/com.myapp E/GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-20-5014-0] syncForReleaseLocked: error dup'ing native fence fd: 0x3000
06-27 14:29:29.441 5014-5159/com.myapp W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during updateTexImage (see logcat for details)
06-27 14:29:29.444 5014-5159/com.myapp W/System.err:     at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.nativeUpdateTexImage(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage(SurfaceTexture.java:240)
        at ly.img.android.opengl.textures.GlCanvasTexture.updateTexture(GlCanvasTexture.java:110)
        at ly.img.android.opengl.textures.GlCanvasTexture.bindTexture(GlCanvasTexture.java:144)
        at ly.img.android.opengl.programs.GlProgramBase_StickerDraw.setUniformImage(GlProgramBase_StickerDraw.java:54)
        at ly.img.android.opengl.programs.GlProgramStickerDraw.setUniformImage(GlProgramStickerDraw.java:27)
        at ly.img.android.sdk.layer.TextGlLayer.onDrawLayer(TextGlLayer.java:675)
        at ly.img.android.sdk.layer.base.GlLayer.glDrawLayer(GlLayer.java:76)
        at ly.img.android.sdk.operator.preview.GlLayerOperation.doOperation(GlLayerOperation.java:225)
        at ly.img.android.sdk.operator.preview.GlScreenOperation.doOperation(GlScreenOperation.java:37)
        at ly.img.android.sdk.operator.preview.GlOperation.render(GlOperation.java:87)
        at ly.img.android.sdk.operator.preview.GlScreenOperation.render(GlScreenOperation.java:47)
        at ly.img.android.sdk.operator.preview.GlOperator.render(GlOperator.java:72)
        at ly.img.android.sdk.layer.PictureGlLayer.onDrawLayer(PictureGlLayer.java:113)
        at ly.img.android.sdk.layer.base.GlGround.onDrawFrame(GlGround.java:244)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1535)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Any suggestion on which could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: I have a similar issue but it restarts the app when trying to do text edit and on 6.0 it does when you try to save the edited photo.